# read manifest.mf while initializing JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am trying to read information from MANIFEST.MF while initializing JAX-RS. I use Glassfish app server.

My first idea was to use the following piece of code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(getClasses().getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
String version = prop.getProperty("Implementation-Version");
```

But this code reads info from another MANIFEST.MF, not from my WAR so I need to use ServletContext:

```
package com.remal.forum.service.configuration.rest;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class Configurator extends Application {

    @Context
    protected ServletContext servletContext;

    public Configurator() {
        ...
        InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

        Manifest manifest = new Manifest(inputStream);
        manifest.getAttributes("Implementation-Version");
        ...
    }
}
```

But the injected servletContext is always null. What is wrong here?

Comment: You need to inject it into the constructor. Fields can't be injected until the object is initialized (constructed)

Comment: I have tried it before. It throws exception:  Parameter interceptedBean of type javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?> from private javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?> org.glassfish.soteria.cdi.LoginToContinueInterceptor.interceptedBean is not resolvable to a concrete type. This is the constructor I tried: public Configurator(@Context ServletContext servletContext)